# How to make multiple values selected in dropdown in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, html-select, multi-select, cakephp-3.x

```
<div class="form-group">
   <?php
   echo $this->Form->input('area', array('label' => false,
       'placeholder' => 'Enter Zone Name',
       'type' => 'select',
       'class' => 'form-control',
       'id'=>'area',
       'multiple' => 'multiple',
       'options' => $areaList)
   );
   ?>
</div>
```

This is my dropdrop for input type select on edit page.

I just want to know how can I make `$arealist` values to be shown selected.

I am using Cakephp 3.x. I am new to cakephp 3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the keys of `$areaList` (which should be a `find('list')` style resultset/array) to either the `default` option (which will be used unless the form context contains data for the field, for example the submitted form data), or to the `value` option (which will hard-select the given values, ie possible form context data will not override it).

```
// ...
'options' => $areaList,
'default' => array_keys($areaList)
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Common Options For Specific Controls](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#common-options-for-specific-controls)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Select, Checkbox and Radio Controls](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-checkbox-and-radio-controls)**